# How to open a modal external page and wait it finish with wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I want to open an external page with wicket wait it be used and closed and continue from that point. Currently we are using:

```java
getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new RedirectRequestTarget(url));
```

but when we close the page, our page loses its session. Is there any way to resolve that? Unfortunately, we must use Wicket 1.4.

**Update:**
I also have tried this:

```java
throw new RedirectToUrlException(url);
```

It also let me without session after open the url.

**Update 2:**
It's possible that is not the session that has been lost, but the page on session.